# generate unique random number and insert it in a column avoiding collision

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

Hi i would like to know what you guys recommend me to do, to generate a random number every day and avoiding collision. This number should be inserted in a column this is my schema:

```
id amount paymentmethod docnumber
1  12.00  cash          123456 (should be the same for all records in that day)
2  15.00  creditcard    123456
3  10.00  cash          123456
```

so in the column **docnumber** what im trying to achieve is to generate a unique number every day, because each day i will empty the table and the table will be filled with N number of values so next day should look like:

```
id amount paymentmethod docnumber
1  12.00  cash          789013 (should be the same for all records in that day)
2  15.00  creditcard    789013
```

so today i can have 10 records in the table but in the column docnumber will be always the same random number, and then tomorrow i will have example 5 records but still the column docnumber will have another random number but in all records, how i can achieve that?

thank you very much.

Comment: Are you saying you empty the tables every day but you need to use a new value for each day?

Comment: Why not just use the date as YYYYMMDD ?

Comment: yes, because in the system im using, at the end of the day i will save all records in the software but will ask a unique docnum so today i use 1234 tomorrow i cant use the same docnum

Comment: @GordonLinoff has the probably the best suggestion. Another option would be to create a dates table and populate it with all the dates for the next x years or whatever and generate a unique docnumber in that table which you could reference each day.

Comment: but how i can populate the same date of today in all records

Comment: Either when you insert them or as an update statement.

Comment: got it, thank you so much Gordon, Sean

Answer (score 0):

One Option is to create a table with given day's ID and delete Ids from it everyday.

```
    create table #IdTrack
    (
     tdate DATE
    ,ID uniqueidentifier
    )
    INSERT INTO #IdTrack
    SELECT
    CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) ,NEWID()
    GO
    Create Procedure IdTrack 
    As
    Begin
         DELETE FROM
         #IdTrack
         where DATEDIFF(day,tdate,GETDATE())>1
    End
```